# Big-Theta: multiplying Theta(n) and Theta(n^2) = Theta(n^3)?

Tags: time-complexity, multiplication, big-o

If f(n) = Θ(n) and

g(n) = Θ(n^2),

then f(n) * g(n) = Θ(n^3)?

Answer (score 3):

## *Problem*

Technically, `Θ(n)` is a set of functions, so we say that `f` *is in* `Θ(n)`, rather than `f(n)` being equal to `Θ(n)`.

Hence, the problem we want to investigate is:

> Let
>
> ```
> h(n) = g(n) · f(n)                                           (*)
> ```
>
> Does `f ∈ ϴ(n)` and `g ∈ ϴ(n^2)` imply that `h ∈ ϴ(n^3)`?

---

## *Preparations*

Let's start by loosely stating the definition of Big-ϴ notation

> **`f ∈ ϴ(g(n))`**
>
> ⇨ For some positive constants `k1`, `k2`, and `n0`, the following holds:
>
> ```
> k1 · |g(n)| ≤ |f(n)| ≤ k2 · |g(n)|, for all n ≥ n0           (+)
> ```

We will make use of this definition below but assume, without loss of generality, that both `f(n)` and `g(n)` above are non-negative for all `n`.

## *Solution*

From the above we can state, for some positive set of constants `(c1, c2, n0)` and `(d1, d2, m0)`, that the following holds

```
f ∈ ϴ(n):    c1 · n   ≤ f(n) ≤ c2 · n,   for all n ≥ n0        (i)
g ∈ ϴ(n^2):  d1 · n^2 ≤ g(n) ≤ d2 · n^2, for all n ≥ m0        (ii)
```

Now, the set of constants `(c1, c2, n0)` (as well as `(d1, d2, m0)`) is not unique; *if* such a set exists, an infinite number of such sets exist. Since `f ∈ ϴ(n)` and `g ∈ ϴ(n^2)` holds, such sets *do* exist, and we can, without loss of generality, assume that we can find a set of constants `(c1, c2, n0)` and `(d1, d2, m0)` such that `c1=d1`, `c2=d2` and `n0=m0` all hold. Hence, we can re-state `(i-ii)` as:

```
f ∈ ϴ(n):    c1 · n   ≤ f(n) ≤ c2 · n,   for all n ≥ n0        (I)
g ∈ ϴ(n^2):  c1 · n^2 ≤ g(n) ≤ c2 · n^2, for all n ≥ n0        (II)
```

for some set of positive constants `(c1, c2, n0)`.

Now, since `n > n0 > 0`, all terms in the inequalities `(I-II)` above are positive, and we can apply `(*)` directly:

```
(I) * (II):

    c1^2 · n^3 ≤ f(n) · g(n) ≤ c2^2 · n^3, for all n ≥ n0      (iii)
```

Now, let `k1 = c1^2` and `k2=c2^2`, and insert---among with `h(n) = f(n) · g(n)`---into `(iii)`, yielding

```
    k1 · n^3 ≤ h(n) ≤ k2 · n^3, for all n ≥ n0                 (III)
```

This is, by `(+)`, the very definition of `h ∈ ϴ(n^3)`, and we have hence solved our problem by showing that:

> For `h(n)` as in `(*)`: `f ∈ ϴ(n)` and `g ∈ ϴ(n^2)` implies that `h ∈ ϴ(n^3)`